# bulk write in Unix using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Is there any way to write bulk data in a file in shell script instead of writing line by line code in file?

In below script, I want to write difference between arrival time and generation time of files in test.csv file.

```
########################################################
echo "Starting the Execution for Time difference\n";
############################################################
# Functions used across the script
datediff() {
    Unixtime=`echo $1 $2 $3 $4`
    Filetime=`echo $5 $6 $7 $8`
    echo $Unixtime;
    echo $Filetime;
    d1=`date -d "$Unixtime" +%s`
    d2=`date -d "$Filetime" +%s`
    echo  $d1;
    echo  $d2;
    TIME_DIFF=`expr $d1 - $d2`
    TIME_DIFF=`expr $TIME_DIFF / 60`
    echo $TIME_DIFF;
    echo "$Unixtime,$Filetime,$TIME_DIFF,$9" >> ../test.csv
}
rm -f ../test.csv;
for i in `ls -1 | grep -v 'DelayCheck.s*'`
do
DayMonth=`ls -lrt $i | awk '{print $7" "$6" "}'`
Year=`ls --full-time $i | awk '{print $6}' | cut -c1-4`
HourMin=`ls -lrt $i | awk '{print " "$8}'`
timeA=`echo $DayMonth $Year $HourMin`
FileYearMonDay=`ls -ltr $i | awk '{print $9}' | awk -F'--' '{print $3}' | cut 
-c2-9`
timeB1=`date -d $FileYearMonDay +'%d %b %Y'`
timeB2=`echo $i | awk -F'--' '{print substr($3,10,13)}' | sed -e 
's/../:&/2g'`
timeB=`echo $timeB1 $timeB2`
echo "Time A is $timeA";
echo " Time b is $timeB";
datediff $timeA $timeB $i
done
echo $?;
```

script is working fine, but the problem is there is over 100k files. So script performance is bad.

I had tried to search is there any way to write bulk data in a file but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Why don't you code that in Python, since you are "python lover"?

Comment: The number of child processes you have on each loop iteration is astounding, many of them are unnecessary, that could badly affect performance.  For example, `timeA=\`echo $DayMonth $Year $HourMin\`` can be written as `timeA="$DayMonth $Year $HourMin"`.  With some work the number of calls to the `awk` programming language, not to mention `ls` could also be reduced or removed.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: Don't use backticks or `$()` or pipes inside code that's called in a loop inside shell scripts that need to be fast. And don't use `>>` repeatedly -- just run one redirection that covers your entire loop.

Comment: ...so, among other things, that means you should be using `find -printf` to generate a stream with *all* your file metadata at once, and then iterating over that stream instead of doing a call for file. And you should be ditching all uses of `$(expr ...)` in favor of the much faster POSIX-native `$(( ... ))` construct for math. And you should be using bash 4.3's built-in timestamp support where possible, and dealing with epoch time (for which regular math suffices) where not.

Comment: Right now, though, your efficiency problem **isn't** actually anything to do with "bulk writes" at all; instead, it's a whole bunch of smaller individual things that are being done badly and would need to be done well. Arguably, covering all of these is beyond the scope of a reasonable single question.

Comment: Thank you for your  valuable suggestion .I will change my script